# How to setup nginx to proxing thing on another server

Tags: nginx, redmine, thin

I have this setup:

192.168.1.1 - as router with custom firewall

192.168.1.2 - as nginx server with php5

192.168.1.3 - as mysql server

192.168.1.4 - as thin server with redmine

I have succesfull installed thin and redirect port 3000 to 192.168.1.4 and i can access to redmine.

But when i try to setup access via domain.com/redmine in nginx i got this:

```
Page not found

The page you were trying to access doesn't exist or has been removed.

Back
```

Nginx conf:

```
upstream thinCluster {
    server 192.168.1.4:3000;
}

location /redmine {
try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @cluster;
    }

    location @cluster {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://thinCluster;
}
```

What is wrong ?

Cheers